How to handle zero-inflated time in Cox proportional hazards model with categorical covariates?
I am using a Cox proportional hazards model to compare the time to an event, adjusting for several categorical variables (X1, X2, and X3). One of these variables, X3, is a three-level categorical variable.
A significant number of subjects within one level of X3 experience the event right at the beginning of the study, resulting in zero-inflated time data.
How should I handle this zero-inflation in my Cox model? Are there specific techniques or model adjustments recommended for this type of data?

Why do you think this is necessary? As far as I know, the Cox model makes no assumption about the distribution of the time to event. (This is one big advantage it has over many other survival methods).

you may wish to read more on resolving ties also. If too many of your events occur at exactly the same time, 0 or otherwise, that's worth looking into.

@PeterFlom It probably violates proportionality of the hazards, depending on how many 0 there are in the other groups and how well the rest of the subgroup matches the high hazard at the start.

@LukasLohse OK, but that can be tested. It's a related but separate issue.

Thank you all for your responses. The subset with a time zero value constitutes 10% of the total sample. Nearly all of these cases fall within a single level of X3,  comprising 50% of that particular level . This level includes patients with deteriorating condition X3.

I've been told, when testing proportionality, to look for the size of deviation not the p-values. How do I assess/measure the size?

The usual assumption in survival analysis is that there is 100% survival at time = 0. As Peter Flom notes, however, the times themselves aren't used for a Cox model. So a common work-around (if it makes sense based on your understanding of the subject matter) is just to change those 0 times to some small number less than the first actual event time.
As Huy Pham notes, there can be issues with tied event times in Cox models; there are nevertheless approximations (e.g., the Efron approximation) that deal with those issues. Read the documentation to know how your software implementations is handling ties.
I agree with Lukas Lohse, however, that this situation is likely to end up with a model that violates the proportional hazards assumption. You won't know until you try. You might consider a two-stage model: a binomial model for an immediate event, followed by a Cox model for those who don't experience the event immediately.

Thank you, @EdM. If the inflation wasn't at zero and occurred at a later time, say time T, how would I handle that?

@AziR it depends on your understanding of the subject matter and how well the proportional hazards assumption is met. That might suggest that there are two different processes leading to events, for example deaths coming soon from surgical complications versus later deaths from recurrence of the cancer that the surgery tried to treat. Modeling a corresponding step function for the coefficients, as in Section 4.1 of the R time dependence vignette, might be called for.
